# Permission denied when i exec Postfix reload in a perl script

Tags: perl, exec, root, reload, postfix-mta

I have a script that normally should reload Postfix, but i got permission denied at /../../reload.pl 11.

And here is my perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
# Script Name : reload postfix
# version : v1.0
#
$ENV{PATH} = '/usr/bin';

print $<." ".$>;

# Relaod postfix (opt)
system('/etc/postfix reload');
```

The result is :

```
0 0
Can't exec "/etc/postfix": permission denied at /../../reload.pl  11
```

The solution is to give the complete path to execute the postfix cmd:

```
$ENV{PATH} = '/usr/sbin';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean:

```
system("$ENV{PATH}/postfix reload");
```

or

```
system("/path/to/postfix/binary/postfix reload");
```

`/etc/postfix` is most likely a config file which isn't executable, hence the permission denied error. You can find the path to `postfix` on your system with `which postfix`

Comment: in the terminal i can execute $postfix reload, after testing your solution i got : No such file or directory

Comment: Use `which postfix` to find the path to the postfix binary

Answer (score 2):

You can reload `postfix` either via the `postfix` control binary itself or via the init script. The init script in turn only executes the `postfix` control binary with `reload` as its argument, so you can just skip it.

The reason you see the original error is that `/etc/postfix` is probably a directory containing the configuration files. You cannot execute a directory.

You should therefore execute the control binary itself. This is usually located at `/usr/sbin/postfix` and not in `/usr/bin`. You also don't need to set the `PATH` for it. Therefore:

1. Remove the line with `$ENV{PATH} = ...`, you don't need it.
2. Change the system call to `system("/usr/sbin/postfix reload");`